# How to find if div with specific id exists in jQuery?

Tags: javascript, jquery

I’ve got a function that appends a `<div>` to an element on click. The function gets the text of the clicked element and assigns it to a variable called `name`. That variable is then used as the `<div>` `id` of the appended element.

I need to see if a `<div>` `id` with `name` already exists before I append the element but I don’t know how to find this.

Here is my code:

```
$("li.friend").live('click', function() {
  name = $(this).text();

  // if-statement checking for existence of <div> should go here
  // If <div> does not exist, then append element
    $("div#chatbar").append("<div class='labels'><div id='" + name + "' style='display:none;'></div>" + name + "</div>");

  // Else
    alert('this record already exists');
});
```

This seems pretty straightforward but I’m getting the error “*Unexpected end of file while searching for class name”*. I have no clue what that means.

```
if (document.getElementById(name)) {
  $("div#" + name).css({bottom: '30px'});
} else {
  $("div#page-content div#chatbar").append("<div class='labels'>" + name + "</div><div id='" + name + "'></div>");
}
```

What’s more is that I want to be able to delete this element if I close it out which should then remove the `div id [name]` from the document but `.remove()` does not do this.

Here is the code for that:

```
$(".mini-close").live('click', function(){
  $(this).parent().remove();
});
```

I added `.mini-close` to the append function as a child of `.labels` so there was a way to close out of the appended `<div>` if needed. After clicking `.mini-close` and attempting to click the same name again from `li.friends` it still finds the `div id [name]` and returns the first part of my `if` statement.

Comment: Unexpected end of file usually boils down to a syntax error somewhere.

`$("div#" + name).css({bottom: '30px'});` is wrong, it should be `$("div#" + name).css('bottom', '30px');`

Comment: Remove() detaches the element from the DOM tree but doesn't destroy it, so a search by ID will still find it, if you'd assigned it to a variable it would still be there, etc. The solution here is if you do find it, append it to the correct div (if it's already there nothing will happen, if it's been detached/removed it will reappear), if it's not found, then create it.

Comment: Duplicate of https://stackoverflow.com/q/31044/12101554 (but not flagging as duplicate as this is a popular, ancient question) (just wanted to link these together)

Answer (score 618, accepted):

You can use [`.length`](http://api.jquery.com/length/) after the selector to see if it matched any elements, like this:

```
if($("#" + name).length == 0) {
  //it doesn't exist
}
```

The full version:

```
$("li.friend").live('click', function(){
  name = $(this).text();
  if($("#" + name).length == 0) {
    $("div#chatbar").append("<div class='labels'><div id='" + name + "' style='display:none;'></div>" + name + "</div>");
  } else {
    alert('this record already exists');
  }
});
```

Or, the non-jQuery version for this part (since it's an ID):

```
$("li.friend").live('click', function(){
  name = $(this).text();
  if(document.getElementById(name) == null) {
    $("div#chatbar").append("<div class='labels'><div id='" + name + "' style='display:none;'></div>" + name + "</div>");
  } else {
    alert('this record already exists');
  }
});
```

Comment: lots of jQuery in the non-jQuery part :p

Comment: @Nick - this isnt working for me.  While troubleshooting I alerted the length of the div id of [name] but it never finds it.

Comment: @sadmicrowave - Can you post some example markup?  It's fairly straightforward so should work pretty easily.

Comment: checking == 0 isn't necessary if($("#" + name).length) { } works just fine.

Comment: @ScottE - That's the inverse though, you mean `!$("#"+name).length)` :)

Comment: @sadmicrowave - Is that your exact code? You're missing a `");` on  the end of that `.append()` line if so, see how your code format coloring is off?

Comment: @Nick - sorry that wasnt my exact code I missed it when copying it to the window.  Still having the specified problem....

Comment: any additional ideas from anyone?

Comment: @sadmicrowave - Can you post your complete code? You don't show where you're creating the `.mini-close` elements, so I have no idea if your selectors/traversings are correct or not.

Comment: I don't know what I was doing wrong but I got it to work now which means your suggestion was valid.  Thanks Nick!

Comment: I don't quite understand how the second example is non-jQuery? Also, `live` is not only deprecated but deleted from v1.9.

Comment: @rvighne I was referring to the specific question piece, the existence check doesn't benefit from or need jQuery in many cases. The answer is from  almost 4 years ago, can edit when not on a phone.

Comment: I think you should do `===` instead of saw  `==`.

Answer (score 70):

Nick's answer nails it. You could also use the return value of getElementById directly as your condition, rather than comparing it to null (either way works, but I personally find this style a little more readable):

```
if (document.getElementById(name)) {
  alert('this record already exists');
} else {
  // do stuff
}
```

Comment: you are right, this works great (I must have been doing something stupid).  However when I replace the alert() with something else I get an error saying: "unexpected end of file while searching for class name".  why is this happening?  See my OP for what I'm replacing my alert() function with...

Comment: any additional ideas from anyone?

Comment: The error sounds like you're missing a bracket or a semi-colon.

Comment: @Philo What if your looking to match specific ID's held in an array to

Comment: You have several IDs in an array, and you want to find each of them? The brute force approach would be to loop over the array and call getElementById for each of them.

Answer (score 37):

Try to check the length of the selector, if it returns you something then the element must exists else not.

```
if( $('#selector').length )         // use this if you are using id to check
{
     // it exists
}


if( $('.selector').length )         // use this if you are using class to check
{
     // it exists
}
```

Use the first if condition for id and the 2nd one for class.

Answer (score 25):

```
if($("#id").length) /*exists*/

if(!$("#id").length) /*doesn't exist*/
```

Answer (score 15):

```
if ( $( "#myDiv" ).length ) {
    // if ( "#myDiv" ) is exist this will perform
    $( "#myDiv" ).show();

}
```

Another shorthand way:

```
    $( "#myDiv" ).length && $( "#myDiv" ).show();
```

Comment: Its just a example inside the if function anything can write, when the id ( "#myDiv" ) is present that will perform.

Answer (score 6):

You can check by using jquery simply like this:

```
if($('#divId').length!==0){
      Your Code Here
}
```

Comment: if($('#divId').length!= 0){
      Your Code Here
}
this would be correct

Answer (score 6):

The most simple way is..

```
if(window["myId"]){
    // ..
}
```

This is also part of HTML5 specs: https://www.w3.org/TR/html5/single-page.html#accessing-other-browsing-contexts#named-access-on-the-window-object

```
window[name]
    Returns the indicated element or collection of elements.
```

Comment: This looks good but there's now a note https://www.w3.org/TR/html5/single-page.html#named-access-on-the-window-object that "relying on this will lead to brittle code".

Answer (score 5):

Here is the jQuery function I use:

```
function isExists(var elemId){
    return jQuery('#'+elemId).length > 0;
}
```

This will return a boolean value. If element exists, it returns true.
If you want to select element by class name, just replace `#` with `.`

Answer (score 3):

You can handle it in different ways,

**Objective** is to check if the div exist then execute the code. Simple.

**Condition:**

```
$('#myDiv').length
```

**Note:**

```
#myDiv -> < div id='myDiv' > <br>
.myDiv -> < div class='myDiv' >
```

This will return a number every time it is executed so if there is no div it will give a Zero [0], and as we no 0 can be represented as false in binary so you can use it in if statement. And you can you use it as a comparison with a none number. while any there are three statement given below

```
// Statement 0
// jQuery/Ajax has replace [ document.getElementById with $ sign ] and etc
// if you don't want to use jQuery/ajax 

   if (document.getElementById(name)) { 
      $("div#page-content div#chatbar").append("<div class='labels'>" + name + "</div><div id='" + name + "'></div>");
    }

// Statement 1
   if ($('#'+ name).length){ // if 0 then false ; if not 0 then true
       $("div#page-content div#chatbar").append("<div class='labels'>" + name + "</div><div id='" + name + "'></div>");
    }

// Statement 2
    if(!$('#'+ name).length){ // ! Means Not. So if it 0 not then [0 not is 1]
           $("div#page-content div#chatbar").append("<div class='labels'>" + name + "</div><div id='" + name + "'></div>"); 
    }
// Statement 3
    if ($('#'+ name).length > 0 ) {
      $("div#page-content div#chatbar").append("<div class='labels'>" + name + "</div><div id='" + name + "'></div>");
    }

// Statement 4
    if ($('#'+ name).length !== 0 ) { // length not equal to 0 which mean exist.
       $("div#page-content div#chatbar").append("<div class='labels'>" + name + "</div><div id='" + name + "'></div>");
    }
```

Answer (score 1):

put the id you want to check in jquery is method.

```
var idcheck = $("selector").is("#id"); 

if(idcheck){ // if the selector contains particular id

// your code if particular Id is there

}
else{
// your code if particular Id is NOT there
}
```