# Find out div with class name and remove &nbsp; before and after it

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I have a formatted text field which contains..

```
"this is some text node&nbsp;
<div class="myClass">contents....</div>
&nbsp;some more text node&nbsp;
<div class="myClass">contents....</div>
&nbsp;"
```

..like this.

Now i want to remove all the surrounding "`&nbsp`" to those divs which has `class="myClass"` only i.e the "`&nbsp`" before and after those divs.

I have gone through this link but it is not solving my problem

[jquery how to find if div with specific id exists](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3373763/jquery-how-to-find-if-div-with-specific-id-exists)

Thanks in advance.

Comment: first of all, your string is invalid due to nested same quote marks. typo or error, still please post a valid string. also, please show us what code have you tried so far

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I might go for something like

```
var text = '"this is some text node&nbsp;<div  class="myClass"> contents....</div>&nbsp;some more text node&nbsp;<div  class="myClass"> contents.... </div>&nbsp;"';

var $ct = $('<div />', {
    html: text
});

$ct.find('.myClass').each(function () {
    if (this.nextSibling && this.nextSibling.nodeType == 3) {
        this.nextSibling.data = this.nextSibling.data.replace(/^\s+/, '');
    }
    if (this.previousSibling && this.previousSibling.nodeType == 3) {
        this.previousSibling.data = this.previousSibling.data.replace(/\s+$/, '');
    }
})

var html = $ct.html();
```

Demo: [Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/arunpjohny/yz3Lhmqw/)

Comment: This code is working good . But the only problem is if there is &nbsp; more then one time i.e say &nbsp;&nbsp;<div>... it is deleting both the &nbsp. but i need to delete only the immediate one.

Comment: @koushik in that case change the `\s+` to `\s`

Comment: @Mr. Arun. Thanks a lot. I just modified your code a little and that worked for me. i posted my working code also.

Answer (score 0):

you can replace '' instead of '& nbsp;',

```
$('.myClass').html($('.myClass').html().replace('&nbsp;',''));
```

or try like this,

```
$('.myClass').html(function(i,h){
return h.replace(/&nbsp;/g,'');});
```

Comment: this will only replace the first occurrence of `&nbsp;`

Comment: this will replace all &nbsp; as well

Comment: @hex494D49 he edited his answer after i corrected him. anyways @Jey, OP stated that this string is coming from a text field which means that `$('.myClass').html()` *is a bad idea*. `.value` should be used to get the input of input fields.

Answer (score 0):

```
var text = '"this is some text node&nbsp;&nbsp; <div  class="myClass"> contents....</div> &nbsp;&nbsp;"';    
var $ct;
$ct = $('<pre />', {
    html: text
});

$ct.find('.myClass').each(function () {
    if (this.nextSibling && this.nextSibling.nodeType == 3) {        
        var r = this.nextSibling.data;
        this.nextSibling.data = this.nextSibling.data.replace(String.fromCharCode(160), '');
        var s = this.nextSibling.data;
        this.nextSibling.data = this.nextSibling.data.replace(/^&nbsp;/, '');
    }
    if (this.previousSibling && this.previousSibling.nodeType == 3) {
        this.previousSibling.data = this.previousSibling.data.replace(String.fromCharCode(160), '');
        this.previousSibling.data = this.previousSibling.data.replace(/&nbsp;/, '');
    }
})

var html = $ct.html();
alert(html);
```

Thanks to all. I just modified Mr. Arun P johny's code a little. And thats worked for me perfectly. In his code it was deleting blank space also, but i wanted to delete &nbsp only.