# check if list has element with same id

Tags: jquery

I have following html code.

```
<div class="list">
   <p id="item1">Item 1</p>
   <p id="item2">Item 2</p>
   <p id="item3">Item 3</p>
   <p id="item4">Item 4</p>
</div>

<input name="item1" type="checkbox"/>
<input name="item6" type="checkbox"/>
<input name="item5" type="checkbox"/>
```

And when i click on checkbox i want to add new `<p>` tag to the `<div>` with `id` like input's `name`.

```
$('input').click(function(){
   $('.list').append('<p id="' + $(this).attr("name") + '"</p>'); 
});
```

But items with the same id should not be repeated! How can i check it?
I'm thinking i need to loop through my list of `<p>` something like this

```
$('.list p').each(function(){
    if (..element with same id exists..) {
        ....    
    } else {
       ('.list').append('<p id="' + $(this).attr("id") + '"</p>');    
    }
});
```

Comment: what should happen if you uncheck an item

Comment: can't repeat ID's, they are unique by definition

Comment: ID is something that needs to be unique. You are trying to create two elements with the same ID. Which is very very wrong.

Comment: it doesn't matter in this situation, the question was about right condition "if"

Comment: like http://jsfiddle.net/arunpjohny/gtdoek19/1/ ?

Comment: Alexandros, i know it matters, but question the question was not about this

Answer (score 0):

You can use the length of paragraph elements in `.list` and and it in id variable in the end to make them unique:

```
$('input').click(function(){ 
  if($(this).is(':checked')){// on checked true
  var p_length=$('.list p').length; //find length of p elements
  if(p_length==0)
    $('.list').append('<p id="' + $(this).attr("id") + '"</p>');    
  else
    $('.list').append('<p id="' + $(this).attr("name")+"_"+p_length + '"</p>'); 
 }
});
```

Comment: no, i need condition if. i don't need to change id.

Comment: May fail in some cases!

Comment: will append an element if user unchecks checkbox too

Answer (score 0):

You can check the length prop of selected objects by selecting it through id:

```
$("#YourId").length >0 //this means id already exist.
```

here are the ref links:

[http://learn.jquery.com/using-jquery-core/faq/how-do-i-test-whether-an-element-‌​exists/](http://learn.jquery.com/using-jquery-core/faq/how-do-i-test-whether-an-element-%E2%80%8C%E2%80%8Bexists/)

[jquery how to find if div with specific id exists](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3373763/jquery-how-to-find-if-div-with-specific-id-exists)

Comment: You can see this also [http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3373763/jquery-how-to-find-if-div-with-specific-id-exists](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3373763/jquery-how-to-find-if-div-with-specific-id-exists) and   [http://learn.jquery.com/using-jquery-core/faq/how-do-i-test-whether-an-element-exists/](http://learn.jquery.com/using-jquery-core/faq/how-do-i-test-whether-an-element-exists/)

Comment: ok..yup , you are right. I was thinking trying to count more than one which doesn't work http://jsfiddle.net/fp8trt0u/  Got a bit ahead of myself

Answer (score 0):

Try this  `$(element).has('#id');`

```
   if( $('.list').has('#foo') )
{
  //dont append
}
else
{
//append
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
$('input').on('click', function(){
    inputId = $(this).attr('name');
    console.log($('.list').find('#' + inputId));
    if($('.list').find('#' + inputId).length === 0)
    {
        $('.list').append('<p id="' + inputId + '"></p>'); 
    }
});
```

[DEMO](http://jsfiddle.net/kb6wtorv/)