# I am adding an element when button is clicked, but if exists it shouldn't

Tags: javascript, jquery

I am adding div element after a button is clicked, but only if it doesn't already exist (from a previous click).

Currently it keeps adding the element as the new DOM doesn't seem to be picked up by JQuery.

```
   var validationMessage = function(msg, elemId) {
      var valId = elemId + "_valId";
      if($(valId).length == 0) {
          $("<div id='" + valId + "' class='error-message'>" + msg + "</div>").insertAfter(elemId);
      }
    };
```

I run validationMessage in my click event:

```
$("#ele1").click(function(e) {
   // validationMessage called in here
});
```

Why doesn't jQuery pickup the new DOM?

I'm using 1.9.1

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Click event doesn't work on dynamically generated elements](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6658752/click-event-doesnt-work-on-dynamically-generated-elements)

Comment: Shouldn't it be `if ($("#"+valId).length == 0) {` ?

Comment: @Brianbcr666Ray not in my case, elemId includes the # already (I will rename elemId to elemSelector)

Comment: Your question is kinda confusing. Here's a Stack answer for creating divs in jquery http://stackoverflow.com/questions/867916/creating-a-div-element-in-jquery

Comment: @Blankman then don't you need to strip the "#" off of valId in `$("<div id='" + valId + "' class='error-message'>" + msg + "</div>").insertAfter(elemId);` ?

Comment: Here is a great Stack answer which i think directly addresses your problem. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3373763/jquery-how-to-find-if-div-with-specific-id-exists

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```js
function genText(text){
if(jQuery){
var ef = document.createElement("div");
ef.innerHTML = text;
ef.setAttribute('id', 'msg');
ef.setAttribute('title', 'this is a title');
if(!document.getElementById('msg')){
$(ef).appendTo("body");
}else{
console.warn("Element already exists.");
}
}else{
console.warn("jQuery hasn't loaded in, yet.");
}
}
```

```html
<style type="text/css">#msg{width: 200px; height:75px; background: white; border: 1px solid #000; color: black; cursor: text; box-shadow: 2px 2px 4px rgb(0,0,0);}</style>
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<button onclick="genText('Hi')">Generate Text</button>
```

You can do this by doing an `if` statement for your ID as shown above. Fortunately, this is quite simple after creating your element, and is probably even easier to do without jQuery unless you're a little more knowledgeable of the abilities of jQuery. This is a really simple example, and since I'm guessing you're going to be using jQuery, I added in the `if` jQuery. One last thing, to prevent errors when jQuery is not loaded, wrap everything around a `try catch` statement so errors don't stop the script.