# Compare prop "title" and "id" of different elements if they match

Tags: javascript, jquery

html:

```
<div class="box-one">
 <img title="element_a">
 <img title="element_b">
 <img title="element_c">
 <img title="element_d">
</div>

<div class="box-two">
 <div id="element_a"></div>
 <div id="element_b"></div>
 <div id="element_c"></div>
 <div id="element_d"></div>
</div>
```

How can I check (with jQuery) by clicking on an `<img>` at "box-one", if there is also a `<div>` that machtes with the ID in "box-two"?

**Example:**

If I click on `<img title="element a">`, the `<div id="element a">` should be the only one that got an extra class called "found".

My bad try:

```
$('.box-one img').click(function() {
    $(this).each( function(){

        var elementTitle = $('.box-one img').prop('title');
        var elementTable = $('.box-two div').prop('id');

        // this part is a shame, sry 4 that //
        if (elementTitle) == (elementTable) {
            $(this).addClass("found");
        }

    });
});
```

Comment: First of all, there is a problem with you id used. You should only specify one id ( https://stackoverflow.com/questions/192048/can-an-html-element-have-multiple-ids ) not 'element a'

Comment: if you correct that then $('.box-one img').click(function() {
        var title = $(this).attr('title');
        $('.box-two #'+title).addClass('found');
    }); is enough for you.

Comment: Yes, you are right, I just forgot the "_" at the IDs here - my fail.

Comment: Btw, you cannot use HTML comments syntax inside Javascript code. Use `// ` for line comments, and `/* comments here */` for block comments.

Comment: You are right, I have corrected it - it was just 4 stackoverflow, its not inside the live code ;)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your `if`-statement is incorrect and might cause instability.

```
$('.box-one img').click(function() {
    $(this).each( function(){

        var elementTitle = $('.box-one img').prop('title'); // wrong, will always get the title for the first .box-one img
        var elementTable = $('.box-two div').prop('id'); // wrong, will always get the id for the first .box-two div

        if (elementTitle == elementTable) {
            alert("found");
        }

    });
});
```

To comply with your answer you could do something like this

```
$(".box-one img").on("click", function () {
    var title = $(this).prop("title");
    $(".box-two #" + title).addClass("found");
});
```

Comment: Thx for help, I tried this one, but now I get always "found".

Comment: This is because you're always getting the `prop` for the first elements found that match `.box-one img` and `.box-two div`. In other words, `elementTitle` and `elementTable` are always `element a` and `element a`

Comment: @Pepe correct, I've revised my answer to comply with your needs.

Comment: Thx for your update, but I get "TypeError: $(...).addclass is not a function"

Comment: @Pepe Minor typo,  it's supposed to be `.addClass`. Sorry about that.

Comment: Ah, damn, I also missed it ^^ - now it works perfect - big thx!

Answer (score 1):

```
<div class="box-one">
 <img data-title="element a">
 <img data-title="element b">
 <img data-title="element c">
 <img data-title="element d">
</div>

<div class="box-two">
 <div id="element a"></div>
 <div id="element b"></div>
 <div id="element c"></div>
 <div id="element d"></div>
</div>



const boxOne = document.querySelectorAll('.box-one img');
const boxTwo = document.querySelectorAll('.box-two div');

// boxOne[0].dataset.title - get title for the first element
// boxTwo[0].id - get id for the first element

    boxOne.forEach((item) => {
      boxTwo.forEach(div => {
        if (item.dataset.title === div.id) {
          // your custom logic
        }
      })
    })
```

Comment: Thx for help - looks professional - I am not sure how to implantate this. I miss the click function and so on, or I am wrong?

Answer (score 1):

Try this.

I think you need each loop for a divs in box-two, instead of  an clicked image,
so you can compare the title of clicked image with all id of div in box-two.

```
$('.box-one img').click(function() {
    var elementTitle  = $(this).prop('title);

    $('div.box-two').find('div').each( function(){
        var elementTable = $('.box-two div').prop('id');

        <!-- this part is a shame, sry 4 that --->
        if (elementTitle) == (elementTable) {
            $(this).addClass("found");
        }

    });
});
```

Answer (score 1):

This is really easy to achieve without any jQuery. I have added some basic CSS so things can be tried out. Find the code commented below:

```js
const boxOne = document.querySelector('.box-one');

// we're adding a so-called "delegate listener" on the parent element of the images
// click events "bubble" upwards in the DOM, we're catching it at <div class="box-one">
boxOne.addEventListener('click', function(event) {
  // the element that received the click is available as event.target
  if (event.target.tagName === 'IMG' && event.target.title) { // if an img was clicked
    // find the div whose id corresponds to the title of the img that was clicked
    const div = document.getElementById(event.target.title);
    if (div) { // if that div exists
      div.classList.add('found'); // add found to its classlist
    }
  }
})
```

```css
.box-one {
  border: 1px solid #f2f2f2;
}

.box-one img {
  background-color: #f2f2f2;
  padding: 10px;
}

.box-two {
  border: 1px solid #e8e8e8;
}

.box-two div {
  border: 1px solid #ddd;
  padding: 10px;
}

div.found {
  border-color: green;
}

div.found::before {
  content: "Found!";
}
```

```html
<div class="box-one">
  <img title="element a">
  <img title="element b">
  <img title="element c">
  <img title="element d">
</div>

<div class="box-two">
  <div id="element a"></div>
  <div id="element b"></div>
  <div id="element c"></div>
  <div id="element d"></div>
</div>
```

Comment: Also big thx for your help, but I like BRO_THOM jQuery way a bit more.

Comment: @Pepe I highly recommend staying away from jQuery until you are already very proficient in native Javascript.

Answer (score 0):

I found this while searching on SO: https://stackoverflow.com/a/3373767/9590929

Also with vanilla JavaScript, you don't need the hash (#) e.g. document.getElementById('id_here') , however when using jQuery, you do need to put hash to target elements based on id just like CSS.

Comment: Thx 4 the tip, I will take a look.

Answer (score 0):

Please make it simple and ignore container box-two because your already put the elementId in your box one image attributes.

```
$('.box-one img').click(function() {
     var target_id = $(this).attr('title');
     $('#'+target_id).addClass("found");
});
```